# Grouping phrases in a string in Java

Tags: java

I have string

```
String in = "Row: 1, Seat: 1, Row: 1, Seat: 2, Row: 1, Seat: 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Row 5: Seat 9
```

And i want to get it:

```
String out = "Row: 1, Seat: 1, Seat: 2, Seat: 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Seat 9
```

How i can do this? Maybe via regular expressions?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Personally, I don't see how regex would be linked to this.

Comment: What is the logic here ? did you tried something ?

Comment: This string seems to be generated from some data structure so I'd suggest you try to directly work with that. If you only have the string you _might_ be able to extract the data via parsing (regex _could_ help here), group the elements and reconstruct the string. However, there's already multiple patterns in your string: what's the difference between `Row: 1, Seat: 3`  and `Row 4: Seat 10`?

Comment: the logic is to group the same rows, for example to make  from "Row 1: Seat 1, Row 1: Seat: 2" to "Row: 1, Seat: 1, Seat 2"
i have thoughts about regex "Row: \d"

Comment: But your string is not in the same format, there are couple of rows separated with comma and few of them are not:
`String in = "Row: 1, Seat: 1, Row: 1, Seat: 2, Row: 1, Seat: 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Row 5: Seat 9`   -------   `Row: 1,Seat: 1`  -> `Row 4: Seat 10`   This does not make any sense

Comment: sorry, not a very good example
then let the line be like this:

String in = "Row 1: Seat 1, Row 1: Seat 2, Row 1: Seat 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Row 5: Seat 10"

and out string:

"Row 1: Seat 1, Seat 2, Seat 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Seat 10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Stream.of(in.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
    .map(e -> e.split("\\s*:\\s*"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));

String out = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": "
        + e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

System.out.println(out);
```

output:

```
Row 1: Seat 1, Seat 2, Seat 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Seat 10
```

Comment: I must say you solved it in a more neat way than me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> rowToSeats = Arrays.stream(in.split(","))
        .map(s -> {
            String[] split = s.split(": ");
            return new Integer[]{Integer.parseInt(split[0].substring(split[0].indexOf("Row ") + "Row ".length())),
                    Integer.parseInt(split[1].substring(split[1].indexOf("Seat ") + "Seat ".length()))};
        })
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(pair -> pair[0], Collectors.mapping(pair -> pair[1], Collectors.toList())));

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
rowToSeats.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .forEach(row -> {
            strBuilder.append("Row " + row.getKey() + ": ");
            row.getValue().forEach(seatNumber -> strBuilder.append("Seat ").append(seatNumber).append(", "));
        });

strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length()-2);
strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length()-1);

System.out.println(strBuilder);
```

Output:

```
Row 1: Seat 1, Seat 2, Seat 3, Row 4: Seat 10, Row 5: Seat 8, Seat 10
```